# What is a good way to implement a custom authentication in Firebase?

Tags: authentication, customization, firebase

I've done some things using firebase (so cool).

I'm doing the custom login, I've generated a AUTH_TOKEN (using nodejs).

My question is if I need to pass in all my page that I wanna to protect the code below?

Peace,

Tulio Cruz

`var dataRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com");`

```
    // Log me in.
    dataRef.auth(AUTH_TOKEN, function(error, result) {
      if(error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', result.auth);
        console.log('Auth expires at:', new Date(result.expires * 1000));
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. If you want to know if you need to call auth every time a page is loaded -- yes you do. When using custom login with the low-level auth() api call, we don't do any session management for you.

You only need to call auth() once per page load though -- not once for each Firebase reference.

Comment: Hey Andrew, you have answered my question. Tks! :)

Comment: Is it possible to use custom login with Simple login?  If you pass a token into $login, it fails.